# Select all product woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I would select all woocommerce products in my wordpress solution trough wc_get_products() and pass the result in a JSON variable returned by the function created.

How did you develop it? I can show screenshots if it is necessary. Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like this:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$results = new WP_Query( $args );
$products = $results->posts;
$json_data = array();

foreach($products as $product){
    $product = wc_get_product( $product->ID);
    if($product->is_visible()){
        $json_data[] = array(
            'id'=> $product->get_id(),
            'title'=> $product->get_title(),
         );
    }
}

$output= json_encode($json_data);

reutrn $output
```

this part get all the products (active, inactive, and all statuses)

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$results = new WP_Query( $args );
```

so if you want to use it, it is better to consider some verification for products for instance

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
);
$results = new WP_Query( $args );
```

in this line:

```
 if($product->is_visible())
```

you could filter products, for instance out of stock or not visible etc

finally this line encode your data to json:

```
$output= json_encode($json_data);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll verify and then I'll let you know.